# Layout encourages accidental clicks - interstitial ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, admob, cordova-plugins, ionic3

Please Can someone help me with my ads on my app , i get this message from admob :

Format that encourages accidental clicks - Interstitials:
Publishers are not permitted to encourage users to click on AdMob interstitial ads in any way. Please review how you implement interstitial ads, considering the following incompatible implementations:

Interstitials that load unexpectedly while the user is viewing the app's content.

my code :

```
ionViewCanEnter() {
```

let bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
autoShow: true,
id: ‘ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx’,
};

```
this.admob.banner.config(bannerConfig);

this.admob.banner.prepare().then(() => {
    // success
}).catch(e => console.log(e));



let interstitialConfig: AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig = {
  autoShow: true,
  id: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
};

this.admob.interstitial.config(interstitialConfig);

this.admob.interstitial.prepare().then(() => {
    // success
});
```

}

Please Any help to solve this problem

Comment: Please don't shout...

Answer (score 0):

Are you showing the ad automatically as soon as it is loaded? If so then this means that it will arrive on the user's screen unexpectedly - if this happens at a time when they are interacting with the screen for something else then this will generate an accidental click.